# Retransmit rtsp video without Video Processing

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I have 3 pcs, A<->B->C

Where A is the rtsp server
cumunication between B & C is only 1 way B->C

I want to send a video from A to C

A can only get rtsp requests

My sulution is this vlc pssado code in pc B:

```
vlc rtsp:\\MY_IP&PORT  target:UDP&TARGET_IP&ACODEC=NONE
meaning B get stream from A and retransmit it to C without the audio
```

Is there a way to tell VLC or other program to retransmit the video without Video Processing

Because A is streaming in very low delay and very good compression

Comment: I don't think that you can retransmit it by VLC. I could be wrong on this, although I doubt that.

Comment: Why C can’t connect to A directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with this: http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/ and run it on B.
You probably have to modify the proxy server to just stream your video as UDP from B to C without going through RTSP.

Alternatively you could use testRTSPClient 
 (http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#testProgs) and add a UDP server to testRTSPClient running on B and streaming from B to C.